# Using multiple processes to read a file and sending numbers through pipe()

Tags: c, for-loop, pipe, fork, child-process

I have to use `fork(2)` to make as many children as inputted by the user.

Then I need them to split up the work reading a txt file of coordinate points comparing the distance between them to an inputted distance.

Then they add their count of how many points are within the distance given. Each child has to write their count to the pipe and the parent has to read each count and add it to the total and then print it out. Here is my code:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int distance = atoi(argv[1]);
   if ( argc != 3 || sscanf( argv[ 1 ], "%d", &distance ) != 1 )
        fail( "usage: pairs <distance>" );
   readPoints();
   int workers = atoi(argv[2]);

   // Compute the square of the distance bound, since that's what we'll
   // need to compare against.
   int dsq = distance * distance;
   // Count up the number of nearby pairs of points.
   int total = 0;

   int fd[2]; // pipe
   if ( pipe( fd ) != 0 ){
       fail( "Can't create pipe" );
   }
   int pid; // child
   int chNum; // child's number
   int c;
   for( chNum = 0; chNum < workers; chNum++){
       c = 0;
       pid = fork();
       if ( pid == -1 ){ //failure
           fail( "Can't create child process" );
       }
       if( pid ==0 ){ // it's a child
           for ( int i =chNum; i < ptCount; i+=workers)
               for ( int j = i + 1; j < ptCount; j++ ) {
                   // Check the squared distance.
                   int dx = ptList[ i ].x - ptList[ j ].x;
                   int dy = ptList[ i ].y - ptList[ j ].y;
                   if ( dx * dx + dy * dy <= dsq )
                       c++;
               }
           close(fd[READ]);
           lockf(fd[WRITE], F_LOCK,0);
           write(fd[WRITE], &c, sizeof(c));
           lockf(fd[WRITE], F_ULOCK,0);
           close(fd[WRITE]);
           exit(0);
       }
       else if(pid>0){ // this is parent
           int d;
           close(fd[WRITE]);
           read(fd[READ], &d, sizeof(d));
           close(fd[READ]);
           total = total + d;
       }
   }
   if(pid>0){
       wait(NULL);
       printf( "Total: %d\n", total );
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

I use a for loop to make the children with `fork(2)`, and then I have them calculate the count and send it to the pipe to be read by the parent. The parent reads  into `d` and adds it to `total`. I was wondering if I am using the pipe correctly to send each child's count to the parent and/or if I am forking correctly so it only comes from one parent. I am getting the wrong total count when I use more than 1 child.

If I use 1 child, the total result is 166428, which is correct, but when I use 4 for example, it gives me 164908. Can someone help me?

Comment: please, properly indent your code when posting it here

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing pipe handling properly.

First off, you don't need to lock / unlock to write to and read from the pipe: writes that are less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes are guaranteed to be atomic. POSIX.1-2001 requires that `PIPE_BUF` is at least 512 bytes; since you're only writing `sizeof(int)` bytes at a time, you're safe (unless `sizeof(int)` is greater than or equal to 512, which is nonsense). See `man limits.h`, under *Pathname Variable Values*:

> {PIPE_BUF}
>
> Maximum number of bytes that is guaranteed to be atomic
>   when writing to a pipe. Minimum Acceptable Value: {_POSIX_PIPE_BUF}

That by itself simplifies the code and reduces unnecessary locking / unlocking overhead.

But the real issue is here:

```
else if (pid > 0) { // this is parent
    int d;
    close(fd[WRITE]);
    read(fd[READ], &d, sizeof(d));
    close(fd[READ]);
    total = total + d;
}
```

You can't close `fd[WRITE]` inside the loop: consider what happens in the next iteration, when you fork the next process. The child process in the next loop will attempt to write to a file descriptor that has already been closed, so an error occurs (and `write(2)` fails with `EBADF`, but you never check the return value of `write(2)` so the code happily ignores the error). Plus, you attempt to close `fd[WRITE]` again and again, so `close(2)` will also return an error (which again, you ignore).

Similarly for `read(2)`: if you close `fd[READ]`, you can't read the results out of the pipe in the next iteration; `read(2)` will return an error and `close(2)` too.

(So the lesson is: do not ignore errors. If you had done error handling properly, you would have a pretty strong clue at what was going wrong)

You don't need to close. The child processes write exactly `workers` integers to the pipe; the parent process reads exactly `workers` integers from the pipe, so this is enough:

```
for (chNum = 0; chNum < workers; chNum++) {

    c = 0;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
        fail("Can't create child process");

    if (pid == 0) { // it's a child

        for (int i = chNum; i < ptCount; i += workers) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ptCount; j++) {
                // Check the squared distance.
                int dx = ptList[i].x - ptList[j].x;
                int dy = ptList[i].y - ptList[j].y;
                if (dx*dx + dy*dy <= dsq) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }

        ssize_t written = write(fd[WRITE], &c, sizeof(c));
        if (written == -1)
            perror("write error");
        if (written != sizeof(c))
            fail("Write failed on pipe");

        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        int d;
        if (read(fd[READ], &d, sizeof(d)) != sizeof(d))
            fail("Read error on pipe");
        total += d;
    }

}
```

The key point is to understand that you need to keep `fd[READ]` and `fd[WRITE]` open as long as you plan to fork new processes that will use the pipe.

Now, that fixes the problem, but you get a false sense of parallelism: reads in a pipe will block by default if no data is available. This means that on each iteration, the parent will not make progress until the corresponding child writes to the pipe. So you're not really parallelizing anything; the effect is the same as having the parent fork, wait for the child to terminate, read the result and add it to total, and then fork the next child (and repeat the cycle).

If you want true parallelism, you have to fork every process and only then start reading from the pipe. Something like this:

```
for (chNum = 0; chNum < workers; chNum++) {

    c = 0;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
        fail("Can't create child process");

    if (pid == 0) { // it's a child

        for (int i = chNum; i < ptCount; i += workers) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ptCount; j++) {
                // Check the squared distance.
                int dx = ptList[i].x - ptList[j].x;
                int dy = ptList[i].y - ptList[j].y;
                if (dx*dx + dy*dy <= dsq) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }

        ssize_t written = write(fd[WRITE], &c, sizeof(c));
        if (written == -1)
            perror("write error");
        if (written != sizeof(c))
            fail("Write failed on pipe");

        exit(0);
    }
}



if (close(fd[WRITE]) < 0)
    fail("Error closing pipe's write channel");

int d;
ssize_t r;
while ((r = read(fd[READ], &d, sizeof(d))) > 0) {
    if (r != sizeof(d))
        fail("read error");
    total += d;
}
```

Note that here we have to explicitly close the pipe's write channel before starting the reads; this is to avoid having the parent hang when no more child processes are actively writing to the pipe. Remember that a read will block as long as there is at least one process with the pipe's write channel open. If the parent process kept the write channel open, `read(2)` would never return because there is a chance that the parent himself could write to the pipe (even though we know it won't). So we have to close `fd[WRITE]`.

Alternatively, since we know that there are exactly `workers` numbers to read from the pipe, we could just do this after the loop instead of closing the write channel:

```
int d;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
    if (read(fd[READ], &d, sizeof(d)) != sizeof(d))
        fail("Failed to read from pipe");
    total += d;
}
```

A couple of other (unrelated) remarks:

- The error message when the wrong arguments are given does not agree with the code. The code shows that `distance` is in `argv[1]` and `workers` is in `argv[2]`, yet the error message passed to `fail()` seems to say that `distance` is in `argv[2]`.
- `argv[1]` is parsed twice as an integer: with `atoi(3)` and with `sscanf(3)`. I'd stick to `sscanf(3)` since you can check the return value to make sure that parsing was successful.
- `workers` is not validated and is converted with `atoi(3)`. Errors are ignored. I'd suggest parsing it with `sscanf(3)` just like you did with `distance` and make sure that it is successful.
- The correct type to store a `pid` is `pid_t`, not `int`. Please use the correct type (you might have to include `sys/types.h` in addition to `unistd.h`).

Here's the final version with all of this sorted out:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int distance;
    int workers;

    if (argc != 3 || sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &distance) != 1 || sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &workers) != 1)
        fail("usage: <distance> <workers>");

    readPoints();

    // Compute the square of the distance bound, since that's what we'll
    // need to compare against.
    int dsq = distance * distance;
    // Count up the number of nearby pairs of points.
    int total = 0;

    int fd[2]; // pipe
    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        fail("Can't create pipe");

    pid_t pid;
    int chNum; // child's number
    int c;

    for (chNum = 0; chNum < workers; chNum++) {

        c = 0;
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
            fail("Can't create child process");

        if (pid == 0) { // it's a child

            for (int i = chNum; i < ptCount; i += workers) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < ptCount; j++) {
                    // Check the squared distance.
                    int dx = ptList[i].x - ptList[j].x;
                    int dy = ptList[i].y - ptList[j].y;
                    if (dx*dx + dy*dy <= dsq) {
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }

            ssize_t written = write(fd[WRITE], &c, sizeof(c));
            if (written == -1)
                perror("write error");
            if (written != sizeof(c))
                fail("Write failed on pipe");

            exit(0);
        }
    }

    if (close(fd[WRITE]) < 0)
        fail("Error closing pipe's write channel");

    int d;
    ssize_t r;
    while ((r = read(fd[READ], &d, sizeof(d))) > 0) {
        if (r != sizeof(d))
            fail("read error");
        total += d;
    }


    printf("Total: %d\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanations really helped me understand everything better. I am just starting to learn this so it was very helpful.